# Dynamically loading client C++ dll using ACE_DLL giving error as Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, dll, ace

I want to dynamically load the client dll in my C++ Windows application. So I am using ACE_DLL. I want to create the object of the class in client dll in my application .
So I have written a wrapper class. One of its member function creates the object of ACE_DLL.
Then using that object I am loading the client dll. Next I am calling the symbol function through ACE_DLL object and passing the mangled name of constructor of the class in client dll. Next I am calling the function pointer (_entry ) which contains address of the constructor but this time I am getting error as "Unhandled exception (Access violation)"

Please let me know if my approach is correct. Below are the calling sequence in my application.

---

`ACE_DLL* _pDll;`
`typedef Test* (*TestFP)();`
`TestFP _entry;`

---

`_pDll = new ACE_DLL();`

`_pDll->open("dllname_to_be_opend");`

`std::string sSymbol = "Test";` // mangled name of the Test class constructor in client dll

`_entry =  (TestFP) _pDll->symbol(sSymbol.c_str());`

`Test *obj = _entry();` // Unhandled exception at 0x00362b2f in Testdll.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00362b0c.

---

Thank you,
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

That looks about right. Can you run ACE_wrappers/tests/DLL_Test.exe? If that works then compare the test code to yours more closely.

Comment: No. My Test application is not running. Giving the error as Unhandled exception. I am confused if, I can get the address of the Test class constructor in client dll using symbol() method and then call this function pointer to create the object of Test class.

Comment: If the test program isn't running either, it's most likely a build problem. I recommend comparing your build setup to one on the build scoreboard (http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/scoreboard/) that most closely matches your environment and see what's different. Once you can get the DLL_Test working, go back and re-try your program.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have presented i.e.

```
_pDll = new ACE_DLL();
_pDll->open("dllname_to_be_opend");
std::string sSymbol = "Test"; 
_entry =  (TestFP) _pDll->symbol(sSymbol.c_str());
```

does not verify that the return value of `ACE_DLL::open` call is zero (0 for success, -1 on failure) or that the return value of `ACE_DLL::symbol` call is not zero (0 is returned on failure).